# How do I know whether I feel head vibrations/sensations while singing?

Tags: voice, health

My question is that how do I know whether I feel head vibrations while singing? In a book, it says that head vibrations are centered mostly around the eyes and bridge of the nose. Later on in the book, it says that head sensations are experienced above the hard palate. By the way, where is that? I do not feel vibrations in any of those places, instead I feel it in the pharynx, where the air is coming out.

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: Hard palate is the top of your mouth.  You can control how much of your vocalization projects into your head and "mask".  You will probably get more vibration in your head when singing higher notes.  You can consciously shift where you place the vibrations (try humming through your nose with your mouth closed).  To feel the vibration you might have to sing louder, in your upper range, make a conscious effort to place your vocalization in your mask (face) and press hard on your cheek bones or upper teeth.

Comment: @RockinCowboy So basically, you are saying that I can control how much vibration I want to project into my head by singing higher notes, but to feel the vibration, I should sing louder while singing those higher notes? But where is the vibrations supposed to be felt?

Comment: The control is more than just singing high notes.  You can place the high notes in different parts of your head (did you try humming through your nose?).  The vibrations will be felt in different parts of your face depending on where you place it.  For example, when you close your mouth and hum through your nose (which you can also do with your mouth open with practice) the vibrations will be in your nose on the front of your face.  With practice you might learn to sing in a way that causes your cheekbones or top teeth to vibrate - or even your temples.

Answer (score 1):

"How do I know whether I feel" is not a sensible question.  The only person qualified to know what you feel is yourself.

At any rate, for singing you want to *project* your voice.  You are *not* interested in getting your neck or pharynx to vibrate but rather the air in the ear of the listener.

If you are singing efficiently, your vocal cords are working against reasonable mechanical and acoustical resistance and can transfer a good amount of energy to the air with comparatively small movement/vibration themselves.  This resistance comes from resonators provided by good posture, breath support, an unconstricted throat singing into the resonances of your head cavities and the room behind it.  When doing that, it is usual to feel the resulting vibrations in the "mask".

So to come back to your original question: when you don't feel vibrations, you know that you don't feel vibrations.  It's as simple as that.  You can either change your sensitivities or the sensations or both.  Once your sensitivity manages to connect with sensations, either by different attention or by different vocal production, you can use that feedback for improving your actions.